# Loading a ListView Adapter in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I am trying to load an `Adapter` from a SQLite database and I cannot seem to wrap my head around how this works. I am extremely new to Android and Java programming so forgive if I stumble around some of the obvious.

I understand that to have a "proper" database setup I must have the 3 java files, the Main, DatabaseHandler and the class for whatever my table is, so getting there. I have most of working in some form but I cannot seem to get my ListView to load with the rows in my table.

I only have one table with two columns, ID and Item. The code in the DatabaseHandler to get all the items is shown below:

```
public List<Item> getAllItems()
{
    List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ITEMS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {
            Item item = new Item();
            item.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            item.setItem(cursor.getString(1));
            itemList.add(item);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return itemList;
}
```

How do put that into a `ListView Adapter` in the main activity? This is what I tried below and it did not work I was getting pointer positions instead:

```
    List itemArray = db.getAllItems();
    //Define a new Adapter
    ArrayAdapter<List> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<List>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, itemArray);

    //Bind the adapter to the listView
    itemView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

How do I load the items in?

Thanks for any help given.

Socaprice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `SimpleCursorAdapter` here. You won't have to parse anything yourself and you won't need a custom adapter.

First adjust your DB method to return a `Cursor`:

```
public Cursor getData() {
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ITEMS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    return cursor;
}
```

Next create and set the `SimpleCursorAdapter`:

```
Cursor cursor = db.getData();
String[] from = new String[] { "StringColumn" };
int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };

SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, from, to, 0);

listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Note: Change `"StringColumn"` to the DB column name that will be used.

**Edit:**
You can fetch the column names afterwards like this:

```
String itemColumn = cursor.getColumnName(1);
```

And then use it for the `SimpleCursorAdapter`:

```
String[] from = new String[] { itemColumn };
```

Comment: Sorry that did not work, getting and error in the log: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist. Replaced the "StringColumn" with "item" since that is title of the column I need but that crashes the app and displays the error I mentioned above.

Comment: @Socaprice I've updated my answer, to help you fetch the values by column index.

Comment: Sorry for being so ignorant since I am new to Android/Java but where am I placing the "String itemColumn = queryResult.getColumn(1)" code? I am assuming it should be in the code where I am creating the Adapter, but I am getting the error 'cannot resolve the symbol 'queryResult'.

Comment: @Socaprice that was my mistake. `queryResult` should be `cursor` and it should be called after `Cursor cursor = db.getData();`.

Comment: I understand, however, it still did not work... :-( now my app keeps crashing. All the code syntax is correct, but as soon as I run it, it crashes. I am going to have to try another way if I cannot get this to work. Do a little more reading and running of tutorials.

Comment: The error show in main activity: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist

Comment: Ok got this to work, not too sure I understand how to use the Cursor adapter but researched the error and found that the Cursor method has to have a column titled "_id" for this to work. Now can anyone explain how to use this same cursor method to delete or update a row in the database? Thanks.

Comment: @Socaprice that sounds like a whole different question. It probably should be researched before asking too.

Comment: you are right, thanks for the help with this one. How do I close this question? Do I just leave it as is or do I have to click on "Answer Your Question". And I will continue to research the delete row using Cursor thing, I have found a few tutorial I got to go through. Thanks again.

Comment: @Socaprice well if any of the answers answered your question, then select it as corrent. You can't otherwise close it as it already has answers in it.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're working with a simple String array, you would have to implement your own adaptation of `ArrayAdapter` along with its `getView()` method in order to actually use it in an `AdapterView`.

[This](https://www.google.co.id/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CCkQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vogella.com%2Ftutorials%2FAndroidListView%2Farticle.html&ei=sLBsVI4NpNyaBdCQgcgM&usg=AFQjCNEmKxSOQWTEdnIteMT1duTBuc2Xsg&sig2=7tS4qJMohVoqjeOb7kmQrg&bvm=bv.80120444,d.dGY&cad=rja) is a great place to start.

But to give you a rough idea on this (and as I don't justify answering an SO question by only giving links) your `ArrayAdapter` would work like this:

- Make an `XML` layout for your `ListView` item. Tis coul be a simple `TextView` or complex, composite `View`.
- Pass your `List<Item>` to the adapter and save it as a global variable (or field).
- Override `ArrayAdapter`'s `getView()` to bind the `TextView`s `Button`s you might have in your XML layout defined above with the actual data from your `List<Item>`. Android automatically called this method, passing the actual position, so that you could call the relevant item in your list.

Comment: Not sure I understand since I am having issues passing the List<Item> in the first place. Plus since I am very new to this I will have to go to the link you posted and see if I can understand what you trying to tell me here. - I already had trouble understanding how to set up the Database Handler and the class to match the table in the database etc. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should write your own ArrayAdapter. Because the normal ArrayAdapter dont know your item, so he can't do anything with it.

See [Custom Array Adapter example / tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown)

Comment: Will have to check the link you posted as I don't know how to write my own ArrayAdapter... sadly enough... :-) in time though.